# Cannot make Axios GET request from my Expo app to my .NET 6 Web Api Backend

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, httprequest, .net-6.0

I am new to Expo and I am trying to connect my frontend to my backend in ASP.NET 6.First I have modified in the launchSettings.json the applicationUrl to my IPV4 ip address and then I have also added CORS in the Program.cs :

```
builder.Services.AddCors(policyBuilder =>
    policyBuilder.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
        policy.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyHeader())
);
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors();
```

Then I have made a simple get call using AXIOS like this :

[GET AXIOS CALL in Expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnNFA.png)

The error is always AXIOS Error Timeout Exceeded. ( or in this case [AxiosError: timeout of 5000ms exceeded] since I have set the timeout to 5000).

Tested the API with Postman and it works perfectly. To mention that my WIFI is private, my iOS is connected to the same WIFI as the laptop.
Tried to use fetch instead of AXIOS and the error is the same.
Does anyone have any solution ? I am strugling with this for like 2-3 days now..

Comment: in postman there is a way to copy the exact request code you are sending to this api. I would copy this and put it into your question. This will show the headers and how the request it being sent. You should also display what the "network" error is. Meaning you inspect element in google chrome then you click on the "network" tab. this tab will show you all the outgoing request your website is sending and recieving. find the one that goes out to this api and tell us the error code.

Comment: please do not use image code